# Arbitrary shape for onClickListeners

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm going to be determing some arbitrary rectangle shapes in an image (borders around OCR-recognized text, in fact,) and am trying to figure out the best way to listen for clicks on them.

I was originally going to draw invisible Rects around them, but then realized that you can't set an onClickListener on a Rect. So I'm trying to determine the most processor- and memory-efficient means to accomplish this.

It seems to me like I can either:

A) Listen for the click on the Canvas, determine the x- and y-coordinates of the click, then run down a list of every single rectangle to see which, if any, it corresponds to.

B) Create invisible/transparent View objects of some kind corresponding to the rectangles I want monitored, and set listeners on them. If this is the case, would it be better to use empty LinearLayout type objects, or something like a TextView? Or something even simpler?

It seems to be like 'A' would be more resource-intensive, but then, I'm not sure what the overhead for creating potentially dozens of invisible views, each with their own onClickListeners, would be.

Any suggestions as to the best way to approach this would be more than welcome. Happy to include any code requested, though it seems like this is an abstract enough question to not need it.

Comment: You should use method A.  Basically use the `MotionEvent` in the `onTouchEvent` callback to call `myRect.contains(x, y)` and see which rect it was.  Although if you're considering using B, then why draw the shapes at all?  Just use custom drawables for your ImageButtons and calculate the buttons' layout parameters at runtime, the same way you calculate the shapes' dimensions.

Comment: You're right, if I went with B I wouldn't draw any shapes: I was doing so originally as a proof-of-concept before realizing I couldn't attach listeners. I'm curious: why do you feel that A is the better method, as opposed to creating invisible Views to listen for the clicks?

Comment: I should clarify, I think the best option would be B because it didn't occur to me until I was done answering that you wouldn't need to draw shapes.  It's always more efficient to use native controls and listeners as opposed to drawing shapes and trying to act on them.

Comment: Great, thanks for the input. So you think ImageButtons would be the lowest-overhead and most appropriate Views to use, or is there not much appreciable difference between the lot?

Comment: There's really no difference.  I think Buttons expose accessibility functions (like for blind people) which is why I always use ImageButton when I want a clickable View.

Comment: I'd +1 your comment if I could. Thanks for the assistance.